# File compressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression

I have written a file compressor in python. The program generates a file filled with sequences of the same character with a random length, and compresses that file. I would like feedback on code readability, efficiency, and any other nitpicks that you find. Any and all feedback is considered and appreciated!

**compress.py**

```
""" Import Statements """
import os
import random
import re
import string

UNCOMPRESSED_FILE = "code/python/compression/uncompressed.txt"
COMPRESSED_FILE = "code/python/compression/compressed.txt"
RE_UNCOMPRESSED_FILE = "code/python/compression/re_uncompressed.txt"

def get_random_letter(previous_letter):
    """ Gets a letter that isn't the previous letter """
    letter = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return letter if letter != previous_letter else get_random_letter(previous_letter)

def generate_file():
    """ Generates file to be compressed """
    previous_letter = "A"
    with open(UNCOMPRESSED_FILE, "w") as file:
        for _ in range(random.randint(10000, 100000)):
            letter = get_random_letter(previous_letter)
            for _ in range(random.randint(3, 9)):
                file.write(letter)
            previous_letter = letter

def compress_file(file_to_be_compressed):
    """ Creates a new compressed file from the past file """
    compressed_string = ""
    characters = file_to_list(file_to_be_compressed)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(characters)):
        try:
            if characters[i] == characters[i + 1]:
                count += 1
            else:
                compressed_string += f"{characters[i]}{count + 1}"
                count = 0
        except IndexError:
            if characters[len(characters) - 1] == characters[len(characters) - 2]:
                count += 1
                compressed_string += f"{characters[i]}{count}"

    with open(COMPRESSED_FILE, "w") as compressed_file:
        compressed_file.write(compressed_string)

def decompress_file(file_to_be_decompressed):
    """ Decompresses passed file """
    compressed_content = file_to_one_line(file_to_be_decompressed)
    decompressed_content = re.findall("..", compressed_content)
    #print(decompressed_content)
    with open(RE_UNCOMPRESSED_FILE, "w") as re_uncompressed_file:
        for pair in decompressed_content:
            letter = pair[0]
            num = int(pair[1])
            re_uncompressed_file.write(letter * num)

def get_file_size(file):
    """ Returns the file size, in bytes """
    return os.path.getsize(file)

def file_to_one_line(file):
    """ Concats all lines in file to one line """
    with open(file, "r") as file_to_read:
        lines = ""
        for line in file_to_read:
            lines += line
        return line

def file_to_list(file):
    """ Converts all the lines into an array of characters"""
    with open(file, "r") as file_to_read:
        lines = ""
        for line in file_to_read:
            lines += line
        return list(map(str, lines))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_file()
    print(f"File size before compression: {get_file_size(UNCOMPRESSED_FILE)}")
    compress_file(UNCOMPRESSED_FILE)
    print(f"File size after compression: {get_file_size(COMPRESSED_FILE)}")
    decompress_file(COMPRESSED_FILE)
    print(f"File size after decompression: {get_file_size(RE_UNCOMPRESSED_FILE)}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DocStrings

`"""Docstrings"""` are not comments.  They are extracted by the `help()` function to return documentation to the user on how to use the module.  As written, if someone was to:

```
>>> import compress
>>> help(compress)
```

They would be given the description of the module as:

> Import Statements

Use comments lines `# ...` for descriptions about the code, and `"""Doc-strings"""` for descriptions of how to use the module/functions.

---

### Don't use Recursion for Simple Loops

```
def get_random_letter(previous_letter):
    letter = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return letter if letter != previous_letter else get_random_letter(previous_letter)
```

Here, you want to generate random lowercase letter which is different from the previous letter.  If Python used [Tail Call Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization), this would be fine; the Python compiler would turn the recursive call into a jump statement to the top of the function.  But it does (and can't, due to the dynamic interpretive nature).  So each recursive call adds another stack-frame.  With a 1-in-26 possibility of getting a duplicate letter, the expected stack-frame depth will never get very large, but it is still the wrong control structure.  Just use a `while` loop.

```
def get_random_letter(previous_letter):
    letter = previous_letter             # To ensure loop executes at least once
    while letter == previous_letter:
        letter = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return letter
```

---

### O(1) memory

Compressing a 1,000,0000,000 character file will require over 32,000,000,000 bytes of memory, which seems a bit excessive.

- the file is read into memory as a long string
- the long string is split into a list of single character strings.
- each character is an object of at least 28 bytes
- each entry in the list is at 4 or 8 byte pointer to the corresponding object.

Yeouch!

Instead of reading the entire file into memory, and then splitting it, and then  writing out the compressed information:

- open the input & output files simultaneously
- read in characters one at a time
- increment a count when the character is the same as the last
- write out the character and count when the next character is different.

Active memory usage: 2 characters and 1 integer.

---

### A string is a `list` of characters

Well, no, a string is a sequence of characters.  But the upshot is the same.  If you want to index a string character by character, just index the string.  There is no need to turn it into a list:

```
s = "HELLO"
s[4] == "O"              # The easy way

l = list(map(str, s))    # Or the hard, and
l[4] == "O"              # memory inefficient way
```

---

### Bug / deficiency

Your `generate_file()` method avoids generating a sequence of more than 9 entries of the same character, but a compression function should be able to handle that, if it happens.

At present, if you compressed `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB`, it would compress to `A15B2`, which would be decompressed as `A1`, a single `A`, followed by `5B` which is B occurrences of the the letter `5` ... which will crash the decompression algorithm.

When your compressing encounters the 9th `A`, it should emit `A9` and then reset the count to zero, so `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABB` would compress at `A9A6B2`.

Or your decompression algorithm should look for all of the digits after the letter, and interpret it as a multi digit number.

---

### DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself

`file_to_one_line` and `file_to_list` contain the same code.  You could write one in terms of the other:

```
def file_to_list(file):
    return list(map(str, file_to_line(file)))
```

... not that I like this function.

---

### Read the Python Docs

You are doing a lot of work to read the file line by line and accumulate the result as a string, when Python allows you to read in the entire file as a string:

```
def file_to_one_line(file):
    """ Concats all lines in file to one line """
    with open(file, "r") as file_to_read:
        return file_to_read.read()
```